# Parsing text from webpage in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, parsing

I am learning JavaScript and what I want to do is search for keywords from a text-based website, given a URL.

An example website would just contain text like:

```
"a" : "nice"
"b" : "nope"
"a" : "try again"
"c" : "whatever"
```

Where I'd just like to find "a" and store what it is connected to. What should I look for in JavaScript that would let me do something like this?

Another example of "text-based" website: http://graph.facebook.com/zuck

Comment: When you say text based, do you mean preformatted text? or is the text inside of (X)HTML tags (presumably form)?

Comment: I am meaning something like this: http://graph.facebook.com/zuck

Comment: That looks more like a JSON response. JSON can be easily parsed in JavaScript. How do you access these "websites" from your JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

That is JSON using the GRAPH api from facebook - However you need to use the [facebook API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) to get at it here is a [tutorial](http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/graph-api-javascript-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/)

Comment: In your example, `person` is not JSON. It is a JavaScript object. And how is this related with the query string?

Comment: Sheez - purist ;) Fixed it now

Comment: So how exactly can I get this JSON object? Say for the example above, I had the URL: http://graph.facebook.com/zuck. How easy would it to find "first_name" and store "Mark"?

Answer (score 0):

The content you want to parse is *so called* JSON. You can parse JSON either using `eval()` (not advised) or some library (there are plenty of them).

The bigger problem is how are going to get this data? If you want to load this script directly from Facebook, you can't use AJAX because of same origin policy.